# 'Var' could not be found C#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, web-services

I have a problem with the code here.

```
namespace LagerService
{
    public class LagService : ILagService
    {
        public Fruktlist[] BesVara();
    {
        using (var db = new LagerDatabasEntities1())
         {

         }  

    }
    }

}
```

It says "var" could not be found. But on this code var is found.

```
namespace Personservice
{

    public class Personservice : IPersonservice
    {
        public PersonInfo[] GetPersonList()
        {
            using (var db = new PersonDatabasEntities())
            {

                var personer = from per in db.Person
                               select per;


                List<PersonInfo> lista = new List<PersonInfo>();


                foreach (var rad in personer)
                {

                    PersonInfo person = new PersonInfo();
                    person.Id = rad.Id; 
                    person.Fornamn = rad.Fornamn;
                    person.Efternamn = rad.Efternamn;

                    lista.Add(person);
                }


                return lista.ToArray();  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the issue on the first code. There the error is "the type or namespace 'var' could not be found". But it works perfectly fine on the second code. I'm a beginner on C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the first code

Since you have a semicolon it terminates there,

Change

**From:**

```
 public Fruktlist[] BesVara();
```

**To:**

```
 public Fruktlist[] BesVara()
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan You have enough reputation that you should know by now that problems caused by typos should be closed, not answered.  The fact that you got 6 upvotes for this answers is embarrassing.

Comment: @cimmanon even i am, but i don't think its a problem caused by typo based on OPs comments

Comment: @Sajeetharan Which comments? And adding a `;` by accident is the definition of a typo..

Comment: @Rob There were days where i dint sleep for a day because of a semicolon, even though its a typo, it is a common mistake of programmers :)